# Integrating a project inside your own project with Maven

Tags: java, maven

I am in the midst of a personal project and I thought it would be cool to implement Text to Speech for accessibility. However, I am a newbie with Maven and can't quite figure out how to "import" the project I want as part of my own project.

I tried to copy and modify the examples' provided poms but I was unsuccessful in building it. My best guess would be to add it as a module, but I am not quite clear on how to do that.

The project in question is here: https://github.com/marytts/marytts

Could any of you suggest how to achieve what I described?

Comment: Compile it locally and add it as a dependency. It doesn't seem to be on central.

Comment: Yeah, it is not unfortunately, but in this way I get to learn something new